# Cythonize Package & Tox Testing

Tags: python, pip, tox, cythonize

I am developing a pypi-package (`*.py`-files), which is being tested via tox. Since compiling the package might yield some performance improvements, I'd like to cythonize it, and also verify using tox that the package is compiled.

For this purpose, I have made the following adjustments:
`setup.py` additions:

```py
import pathlib

from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    install_requires=[
        "Cython>=0.29.21" #<-- new
    ],
    ext_modules=cythonize("mypackage_name/*.py"), #<-- new
)
```

`pyproject.toml` created:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "Cython>=0.29.21"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

And added the following to my existing `tox.ini`:

```ini
[tox]
envlist = py{310, 311}
isolated_build = true ;<-- new

[testenv]
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
commands =
    python -m pytest tests -s
```

In order to test if this is working, I've added the following to a python file in my package:

```py
def compiled() -> bool:
    import Cython
    return Cython.compiled
```

I have created a test (pytest/tox) to see if the package has been cythonized. Here, I just call the above function. **The result is always that it is not compiled.**

A minimal reproducible example can be found here:
https://github.com/CodingTil/Minimal-Example-Cythonize-Package-Tox

---

I have mainly used the following resources:

- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-a-cython-package-to-pypi-8217a6581f09
- https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html
- https://packaging-guide.openastronomy.org/en/latest/extensions.html

Comment: Are you sure tests import compiled code? Without src-layout chances are tests are run in the source tree. Can you provide a [mcve]? A Git repo would be the best; not necessary your exact code, just a test to run.

Comment: I'll get working on the minimal reproducible example. In the mean time, how would I make sure my tests import the compiled code? I thought that was the purpose of my new test

Comment: @phd I have added a minimal reproducible example. Here you can see (after calling `tox`) that the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

I activated a virtualenv created by `tox` and ran the code manually:

```
$ . Minimal-Example-Cythonize-Package-Tox/.tox/py310/bin/activate
$ python
Python 3.10.8 (main, Oct 25 2022, 01:00:56) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mypackage_name import code
>>> code
<module 'mypackage_name.code' from 'Minimal-Example-Cythonize-Package-Tox/.tox/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mypackage_name/code.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>

>>> code.compiled()
False
```

It seems `compiled()` returns `False` even when imported from a cythonized module. I don't know why.